# How to query ACCESS_HISTORY from Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using Snowflake's cloud platform in AWS and Azure. When I attempt to query ACCESS_HISTORY, as documented here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/access-history.html#label-access-history-query

I receive the following error:

```
select user_name
       , query_id
       , query_start_time
       , direct_objects_accessed
       , base_objects_accessed
from access_history
```

> SQL compilation error: Object 'ACCESS_HISTORY' does not exist or not authorized.

I am using the accountadmin role, and as a test I used the sysadmin role. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately access to the ACCESS_HISTORY requires Enterprise Edition (or higher). We will have to upgrade to take advantage of this feature.

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be due to the missing privileges to the SYSADMIN role.

As Accountadmin , run the below

```
GRANT IMPORTED PRIVILEGES on database snowflake to sysadmin;
```

Then use the sysadmin to query ACCESS_HISTORY table ensuring that the context is set correctly or use the fully qualified name.

Answer (score 0):

That's correct, you will need Enterprise Edition, after you have upgraded, try this:

```
use role sysadmin;
select user_name
       , query_id
       , query_start_time
       , direct_objects_accessed
       , base_objects_accessed
from "SNOWFLAKE"."ACCOUNT_USAGE"."ACCESS_HISTORY";
```

where:

- SNOWFLAKE is the shared database
- ACCOUNT_USAGE is the schema
- ACCESS_HISTORY is the view